# c#: get assembly from a using line for standard gac assemblies

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way, given a namespace such as "System.Collections.Generic" to determine which assembly that namespace is in? Assuming I am thinking of just standard libraries or libraries in the GAC. I understand that there are some namespaces for which this is much more difficult, but it seems to be something that could be done from the GAC. (A lot of program editors will automatically find a library for you an add it along with the using line.)

I tried:

`Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("Microsoft.CSharp")).Location`

Which works for some namespaces like the one above, but not for System.Collections.Generic.

(.NET Core 5.0, if it matters.)

Calrification -- I want to know the information at runtime. The purpose is a programmers tool that allows you to specify a namespace and the tool can automatically locate the associated assembly and dynamically load it. (Obviously this won't work 100% of the time, but that is ok. It is supposed to be a quick aid that works "most of the time".)

Comment: To clarify, you really want to know the assembly information at _runtime_, not at compile time?  If so, you may want to explain why, to avoid the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/1031060)

Comment: Thanks, I added a clarification.

Comment: namespaces in the FCL can span across multiple assemblies, e.g. `System.Windows`.
The `Application` class is compiled into PresentationFramework.dll, `DependencyObject` class is located in WindowsBase.dll (as for .NET 5). More over these locations sometimes change between framework versions.

Comment: You can query the location of a type/class easily, just using `Type.Assembly.Location`.

Comment: Agree with @lidqy.  To solve your underlying problem from the clarification, you may want to choose a different path.  Suggestion: define a known list of libraries (or locations that contain libraries), and then do reflection-only loading on all of those to determine which namespaces are inside them.  Likely you will only need to fully load a library once the user has picked an actual _class_ from a namespace, now that lidqy's comment explains that namespaces are often split across multiple libraries.

Comment: I cannot do Type.Assembly.Location without having the assembly loaded to get the type. So that is a bit of a chicken and egg situation.

Comment: Side note: "A lot of program editors will automatically find a library for you" - adding an example of such tool would be nice. Neither VS, VSCode nor Rider do that to my knowledge - they look in list of assemblies for the project and suggest code fixes...